# Real time process dynamoDB table with AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I am currently working on a stream of data that comes from an IoT rule and inputs the readings to a dynamoDB table.

From that I need to rearrange the data to make predictions. For every new data entry, every new row I trigger a lambda function, but I need to get the last 96 table rows to manipulate.

My problem is
1- how can I query the table
2- and transform to something familiar like a pandas dataframe?

In the table I have a timestamp column (the format is still open to be decided)

Comment: Since you mention pandas, I assume you write Lambda in Python. Check boto3 documentation, but ultimately, if you want to Query data, you will have to make an index on the timestamp so you can use it in the query. If you don't, you will use scan, which is much slower, especially on bigger tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately it depends on how your data is structured and how you want to access it. But to answer your question, when DynamoDB Streams invokes your Lambda you can use a `Query` or `Scan` to retrieve the data from DynamoDB.

My assumption here is that you need to retrieve the last 96 updates based on timestamp, `Scan` will not allow you to do that efficiently. You would need to use `Query` however, that will dictate your data model.

Depending on your specific use-case needs, I would create a Global Secondary Index with a static partition key such as `GSI_PK=1` and your timestamp as the sort key

| gsi_pk | gsi_sk | data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-28T07:25:40.824Z | data |
| 1 | 2023-02-28T07:25:40.824Z | data |
| 1 | 2023-03-28T07:25:40.824Z | data |
| 1 | 2023-04-28T07:25:40.824Z | data |

Now you can `Query` your GSI and be sure you are being returned the last 96 items. GSI's are eventually consistent so be aware of that.

```
   response = table.query(
        IndexName='my-index',
        KeyConditionExpression=Key('gsi_pk').eq('1'),
        Limit=96,
        ScanIndexForward=False
    )
```

Comment: What would the 'my-index' be? Should I use the timestamp or some dynamoDB metadata?

Comment: You need to create the index. A static value as your index partition key and a timestamp as your sort key. This will provide you the ability to search for the most recent records based on time.

Comment: So in your example the 'my-index' = 'gsi_pk' ? Or you would you need another column?

Comment: The IndexName is the name of the index that you create. GSI_PK is an attribute you must create for each item you have/add to the table.

Comment: So, from your answer I achieved a solution. I didn't need the index. Also, I needed to add the proper library call to the Key boto3.dynamodb.conditions.Key('gsi_pk').eq('1') (for those learning like me it is not straight forward).

Other than that it works great. Just keep in mind to have a sort key that suits your case.